# Is there a way to restrict fullscreen view of an embedded youtube clip

Tags: youtube, embed, fullscreen, maximize

Is there a way to restrict fullscreen view of an embedded youtube clip?

And it would be better if I can provide the maximum size to that it can 'restore'. I don't want it to go fullscreen but I may need to maximize it in the contained 'frame'.

Is that even possible? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found the solution.

Just to help someone else who may need the same information:

Adding `<param name="allowFullScreen" value="false"></param>` inside the `object` tag does the trick.

Hope it helps.